# Filtering input and output of AC-DC converter

Tags: power, ac, filter

The datasheet for [this AC-DC converter](https://www.xppower.com/portals/0/pdfs/SF_EML30.pdf) does not include any recommended passive components for either the input or output. With most DC-DC converters their are usually recommended passive components on both input and output.

Given 120VAC @ 60Hz input to the EML30US05 (+5VDC output)

1. Is it necessary and/or common to filter the input of the AC-DC converter? If so, what components are used?
2. Can the output of the AC-DC converter be filtered similarly to a DC-DC converter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Varies. CM chokes, DM chokes followed by capacitor in order of relevance on the AC side. I haven’t seen any but capacitor requirements from the manufacturer for the DC output but there probably exists one out there with really bad performance to start with which requires even more. Most don’t need any additional filters. Yours is a good one and does not need any additional filtering to meet the EMC requirements stated in the datasheet. Next question would be if *those* requirements meets the ones needed in your product.
2. The same laws of physics applies to both AC and DC in this regard, but the *standards* you need to meet can be very different. Check which applies to your product.